# Fresh installed Ubuntu shows windows without background

Tags: unity, 15.04

Just installed Ubuntu 15.04. Dell Inspirion 5720 with Optimus system on Bumblebee.

Deleted all games and a few programs and found that in many settings windows background are transparent. Also if you click "Text entry settings" nothing happens. It doesn't affect work but seems to be annoying. Anybody knows how to return the backgrounds?

Uninstalled packages:

[image]

Problem:

[image]

Comment: "Deleted all games and a few programs"... looks like you deleted one you should not have.  Care to tell us what you deleted? (edit the question if you can ;-) ).

Comment: The [list](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fQRX9a-S9QYlU2ZGVsdUljLXc/view?usp=sharing) of programs deleted. If there is another way  to tell you the list, I'm listening

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your issue ? i.e. transparent background

Comment: I do not see anything that should be related to this. It could be the video card driver. See if picking another one from "additional drivers" fixes this.

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fQRX9a-S9QWGJ5VXJKQjdCWTg/view?usp=sharing) for @solsTiCe

Comment: I'm using Dell Inspiron-5720 with Optimus system and had to install Bumblebee , because if I pick a proprietary from additional drivers I get a black screen on a reboot.